# how remove Win32/Sirefef.DT Trojan on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, trojan

today i downloaded a file and open it...
i had eset smart security in my windows 7 ultimate and it did n't recognize that file as a virus(latest update of eset)
sometimes eset found some dll files in windows\system 32 as trojans and cleaned them.
i reset my system and after reboot and quick scan with eset, eset showed me the error below :

```
Operating memory » \GLOBAL??\7571a07c\WINDOWS\$NtUninstallKB54541$\1970380924\Desktop.ini - Win32/Sirefef.DN trojan - cleaned by deleting
```

also i figure out my windows firewall has been damaged and i have the error below about that :
http://forums.malwarebytes.org/uploads/monthly_02_2012/post-107906-0-42645100-1328455443.jpg

after the other reset eset did n't work so i tried to reinstall it(uninstall and install again)
but i could n't install it again because of an unknown error.
please help me to remove that trojan and fix the problems.
i searched many many web sites by google, but i could n't find a good solution.
really appreciate for help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

Comment: hi dear bro, but i am looking for a solution for a specific trojan -> mean Win32/Sirefef.DT...

Comment: @SilverLight it's no use posting here, this is not an malware forum, post in an malware forum like malwarebyte's one which you mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cleaned out sirefef.dt from XP machine.
Only one infected file was found.  Serial.sys in Windows\System32\drivers.

Easy fix = Start in safe mode - delete serial.sys - replace with known uninfected one - reboot - fixed.